# Cloudformation yaml- generate a list of instances in AutoScalingGroup resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am struggling to figure out how to write overrides section of the yaml template for `AutoScalingGroup` resource. Currently, what I have only works for a fixed length of the string. In this case string passed into the template is called `InstanceTypesOverride`.

Below you can see the snippet of the code:

`InstanceTypesOverride = "m5.large,m5d.large,m5a.large"`

```
Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    AutoScalingGroupName: !Ref NodeGroupName
    DesiredCapacity: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
    MixedInstancesPolicy:
      InstancesDistribution:
        OnDemandAllocationStrategy: prioritized
        OnDemandBaseCapacity: !Ref OnDemandBaseCapacity
        OnDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity: !Ref OnDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity
        SpotAllocationStrategy: !Ref SpotAllocStrategy
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateSpecification:
          LaunchTemplateId: !Ref SpotLaunchTemplate
          Version: !GetAtt SpotLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
        Overrides:
          - InstanceType: !Select [0, !Split [ ",", !Ref InstanceTypesOverride ] ]
          - InstanceType: !Select [1, !Split [ ",", !Ref InstanceTypesOverride ] ]
          - InstanceType: !Select [2, !Split [ ",", !Ref InstanceTypesOverride ] ]
```

I would like to find out whether it is possible to write the overrides section of the template so that `InstanceTypesOverride` can handle more instance types or less. As you know, various regions can handle different instances types, therefore it is essential for me to have the ability for the cloudformation to work with different string lengths. Can someone suggest something that would work?

Ideally, I would like to have a cfm template which works with both `InstanceTypesOverride = "m5.large,m5d.large,m5a.large"` and `InstanceTypesOverride = "m5.large,m5d.large,m5a.large,m5ad.large,m5n.large,m5dn.large"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't do this using plain** CloudFormation (CFN). This would require looping mechanisms which are not supported in CFN.

The only way to do it would be through CFN [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or CFN [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).

In the first case  you would have to develop a **custom lambda function** which would create the entire
`AutoScalingGroup` using AWS SDK (e.g. python). In the second case, lambda would also need to be created but it would parse the original template, expand the `Overrides`, and return the modified template to CFN for execution.

Alternative is to not use CFN, but terraform (TF) for example. TF has very reach and extensive support for loops which would allow you to easily do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, TF is not an option as I am relaying on AutoScalingRollingUpdate feature which is only available in Cloudformation.

Comment: @marcincuber So you are left with custom resource or macro in CFN. Otherwise you have to hard-code the values as you do now. If you want to go outside of CFN, you can per-process your templates with, e.g., python to generate different versions of them depending on the `InstanceTypesOverride` requirements.

Comment: @marcincuber How did it go? Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Not yet, but I will probably try using micro at some point to automate my scripts.

Comment: @marcincuber OK. If something please let me know or make new question. Also later, if, if you find my answer helpful, it's acceptance would be appreciated.